# Inherit virtual attributes LDAP

Tags: ldap

Following the OpenDS documentation about Inheriting Attributes, i successfully got the attributes i needed in the child entry as a virtual attributes, but i cant find anything about inherting recursivly, which means:

B inherits from A(real attribute), and C inherits from B(virtual attribute)

Here is my config entry:

```
dn: cn=Inherit From Manager,ou=Organisations,o=group
objectClass: top
objectClass: subentry
objectClass: inheritedCollectiveAttributeSubentry
objectClass: inheritedFromRDNCollectiveAttributeSubentry
cn: Inherit From Manager
subtreeSpecification: { base "ou=Organisations" }
inheritFromBaseRDN: ou=Organisations
inheritFromRDNAttribute: ou
inheritFromRDNType: ou
inheritAttribute: manager
collectiveConflictBehavior: real-overrides-virtual
```

Here is my entries:

```
dn: ou=A,ou=Organisations,o=group
ou: A
objectClass: extensibleObject
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalUnit
manager: ou=somebody,ou=people

dn: ou=B,ou=A,ou=Organisations,o=group
ou: A
ou: B
objectClass: extensibleObject
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalUnit


dn: ou=C,ou=B,ou=A,ou=Organisations,o=group
ou: C
ou: B
objectClass: extensibleObject
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalUnit
```

So the inehritance works from B to A, but not from B to C